# simple CType test Code is not working

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, ctypes

I want to test Ctype with a simple code.

So i just code like below

```
cTypeLib.h
int add(int a, intb);

cTypeLib.cpp
int add(inta, int b){return a+b;}
```

And create library file `libcTypeLib.so`, i used eclipse for it.
(setting -> build Artifact -> shared Library)

And then for test

```
from ctypes import *
lib = CDLL("libcTypeLib.so")
print lib.add
```

But an exception say undefined symbol add.

What is a problem ?

Comment: In your header you need to declare the function as `extern "C" int add(int a, int b);`.

Comment: Does the source file include the header? `#include "cTypeLib.h"`